# Storing and managing related data

Tags: sql, xml, json

I am trying to organize and search data to visualize links between them. What format would be best to store these links?

For example, if I have a bunch of students and add them to a certain class, how would I automatically add that class to each student? Or the other way if a student adds 5 classes, how do automatically add that student to all those rosters?

Comment: If this is information needs to persist and you have an access to RDBMS you can create a `link` table that will establish `many-to-many` relationship between `students` and `classes` tables.